# can't convert date from string

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
{    
    NSDateFormatter *dateReader = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateReader setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"]; // for example

    NSDate *itsDate = [dateReader dateFromString:txtDate.text];
}
```

I am using this code to convert date from string, I get the string from a `UITextField` text.

But every time I am getting "2013-01-04 18:30:00 +0000" this date even my text field's date is different.
So I can't get correct date.
What should I do ??

Comment: user types date in textfield? if yes then probably it's not a good idea at all you should provide user a datepicker to choose desired date.

Comment: Read the fine [manual](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  It's "yyyy", not "YYYY'.

Comment: user is not typing date, its obvious that user selects date from date picker as that textfield's input view is date picker.

Comment: @HotLicks : your solution worked but not fully, I am getting date of yesterday like if I selected today's date then I get yesterday's date.

Comment: Remember that when you NSLog an NSDate object, it shows GMT, not local time.  If you add your timezone offset to the date shown you'll see that it's correct.

Comment: if you're using date picker then your datepicker.date will return a date not string so that way your final output is date now what you want and try my answer for any conversion.

Comment: (I can tell from the above date you printed that you're in India, due to the timezone offset.)

Comment: @HotLicks: how can I add my timezone to get correct output ??

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper: I am converting date to string and then assigning to textfield, so there is no question for going wrong

Comment: @HotLicks: yes, so how can I add my timezone to it ??

Comment: You have the correct output.  You never use NSDate's `description` method (which is what you get when you use NSLog on an NSDate) for anything other than diagnostic dumps.  For "real" output use NSDateFormatter stringFromDate with the formatter's timezone set appropriately, and the output will appear in the proper timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "datefromstring" for ur problem. here i've an example for this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy "];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:YourDate_String];
 NSLog(@"Date: %@",date1);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

these are some functions that will definitely help you to achieve your goal change date format according to your input and output

```
-(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *)stringDate
{
    stringDate=[self trimString:stringDate];
    stringDate = [stringDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+00:00" withString:@""];
    stringDate = [stringDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
    return myDate;
}

-(NSDate *)convertDateToDate:(NSDate *) date 
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDate *nowDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-d H:m:s"];
NSString * strdate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:strdate];
return nowDate;
}

-(NSString *)convertStringToString:(NSString *)DateLocal
{
    DateLocal = [self trimString:DateLocal];
    DateLocal=[DateLocal stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" GMT" withString:@""];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: DateLocal];
    NSString *tt = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSDate *dateReturn = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tt];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE. d MMMM yyyy, hh:mma"];//"Fri. 1 June 2012, 10:29AM"
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateReturn];  
    [dateFormat release];
    return dateString;
}

-(NSString *)convertDatetoString:(NSDate * )date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
    [dateFormat release];
    return dateString;
}

-(NSString *)dateFormatingCommonDateToString :(NSDate *)date formateString:(NSString *)strDateFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:strDateFormat];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
    [dateFormat release];
    return dateString;
}

-(NSDate *)dateFormatingCommonStringToDate :(NSString *)date formateString:(NSString *)strDateFormat
{
    date=[self trimString:date];
    date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+00:00" withString:@""];
    date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:strDateFormat];
    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
    return myDate;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark String Methods

-(NSString*)trimString:(NSString *)theString 
{
    NSString *theStringTrimmed = [theString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
return theStringTrimmed;
}
```